# How do I make a button with a function which rotates an image 180 Degrees?

Tags: python, image, image-rotation

How do I make a button with a function which rotates an image 180 degrees? The variable my image is stored in is

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage("spidey.png")
```

I have already imported the PIL library's ImageTk and Image. I also want to place my image in the middle of my root window.

`from tkinter import *`

`from PIL import ImageTK, Image`
`root=Tk()`

`root.title("Image Viewer")`

`root.geometry("550x650")`

`root.configure(background="black")`

`img = ImageTk.PhotoImage("spidey.png")`

`def rotate():`

`root.mainloop()`
This is my code so far. Please help me out. Thanks.

I tried to write `Img.rotate(180_degrees)` but it didn't work. I expected it to work the first time but it didn't. So again, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation must be applied to the image after you call `Image.open` but before you call `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.  The parameter passed to `.rotate` is just a number (representing degrees), so you'll also want `Img.rotate(180)` instead of `Img.rotate(180_degrees)`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
pic = Image.open("yourpic.png")
rotatedPic = pic.rotate(180)
finalPic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rotatedPic)

label = tk.Label(master=window, image=finalImage)
label.place(x=0, y=0, width=200, height=200)
```

Note that you'll also need something to display the picture inside.  You could use a canvas element and create_image, or (as in my example) use a widget with an `image` property and assign the rotated image to that property.

This was my source for the `.rotate` documentation:
https://pythonexamples.org/python-pillow-rotate-image-90-180-270-degrees/